# Sorted Listview with latter as seprator android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, custom-lists

I want to display list of names along with other information for that I have created custom listview using BaseAdapter Now I want to to display list in sorted order of names and add latter in separator as shown below

```
a--------------------
name: abcd
address: 22nd street
---------------------
name: acdb
address: Link Road
---------------------
name: axyz
address: Shankarnagar
b--------------------
name: bacd
address: Mharajbag
c-------------------
name: cabc
address: Wardha Road
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.


activity_main.xml 

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:divider="@android:color/white"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>

list_item.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name :"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address :"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

    private ArrayList<Character> headerList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        headerList = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String,String> row1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row1.put("name","abcd");
        row1.put("address","1st street");
        data.add(row1);

        HashMap<String,String> row2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row2.put("name","bcde");
        row2.put("address","2st street");
        data.add(row2);

        HashMap<String,String> row3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row3.put("name","cdef");
        row3.put("address","3st street");
        data.add(row3);

        HashMap<String,String> row4 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row4.put("name","acde");
        row4.put("address","4st street");
        data.add(row4);

        HashMap<String,String> row5 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row5.put("name","adef");
        row5.put("address","5st street");
        data.add(row5);

        HashMap<String,String> row6 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row6.put("name","bdef");
        row6.put("address","6st street");
        data.add(row6);

        HashMap<String,String> row7 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row7.put("name","pqrs");
        row7.put("address","7st street");
        data.add(row7);

        HashMap<String,String> row8 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row8.put("name","jklm");
        row8.put("address","8st street");
        data.add(row8);

        HashMap<String,String> row9 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row9.put("name","fghi");
        row9.put("address","9st street");
        data.add(row9);

        HashMap<String,String> row10 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row10.put("name","wxyz");
        row10.put("address","10st street");
        data.add(row10);


        Collections.sort(data,new MapComparator("name"));

        for (HashMap<String,String> row :data){
            if(!headerList.contains(row.get("name").toUpperCase().charAt(0))){
                headerList.add(row.get("name").toUpperCase().charAt(0));
                row.put("header",String.valueOf(row.get("name").charAt(0)));
            }
        }

        getListView().setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this,data));

    }

    class MapComparator implements Comparator<Map<String, String>> {
        private final String key;

        public MapComparator(String key){
            this.key = key;
        }

        public int compare(Map<String, String> first,
                           Map<String, String> second){
            return first.get(key).compareTo(second.get(key));
        }
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        Context context;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list){
            this.context =context;
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,null,false);
                holder.txtHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
                holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                holder.txtAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            if(list.get(position).containsKey("header")){
                holder.txtHeader.setText(list.get(position).get("header"));
                holder.txtHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                holder.txtHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            holder.txtName.setText(list.get(position).get("name"));
            holder.txtAddress.setText(list.get(position).get("address"));

            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder{
            TextView txtHeader;
            TextView txtName;
            TextView txtAddress;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: list is showing separator properly but EditText in listis not working

Comment: where you put EditText ?

Comment: I am adding one edit text and two buttons in each row

Comment: after adding android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in root layout and android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true" in button attributes button has started working but edittext is still not working